# Get member emails when using delta on group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the graph API to get a list of users which have been added to a specific group using the delta feature so I reduce the amount of data that passes through.

However, when I `$expand` on the members property, I'm only getting the id, and not the specific properties I need (mail and some other details) - despite the fact I'm `$select`ing it.

The url I'm using for the query is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$expand=members($select=id,mail)&$select=members&$filter=id eq '<myGroupId>'
```

And the data I'm getting returned is:

```
[...]    
"value": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx",
            "members@delta": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                },
```

I want my members@delta to include the details of the member so I don't have to query for them seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/14587) `members@delta` property contains only the ids of member objects in the group.

Comment: Well that's disappointing.